# Likelihood function with inequality

Tags: probability, bayesian, binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood, beta-function

Suppose $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. bernoulli random variables. Also, $Y=\sum Y_i \sim {\rm binom}(n, \theta)$ and we have a prior beta distribution $\theta\sim {\rm beta}(a,b)$. I want to compute $P(\theta>0.3|\sum Y_i =k)$. Here is my work:

$P(\theta>0.3|\sum Y_i =k)=\dfrac{P(\sum Y_i =k|\theta>0.3)P(\theta>0.3)}{\int_{0.3}^{1} P(\sum Y_i =k|\theta>0.3)P(\theta>0.3)\mathrm d\theta}$.

My computation is according to Baye's rule but does not seem correct, especially the denominator. The "$\theta>0.3$" distorts everything (usually we have $\theta$ equals something instead). I am also wondering if there is a way to get rid of $\theta>0.3$ in $P(\sum Y_i =k|\theta>0.3)$, or at least write it in another way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The beta conjugate prior has the nice property that you just need to bump up the parameters by the number of successes and failures respectively to get the posterior.  Now you should be able to do the computation.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you elaborate on your comment? I don't quite get it.

Comment: The denominator should be the unconditional probability $\Pr(Y=k)$. What you have in the denominator is not that.

Comment: Don't insert the posterior constraint $\theta>0.3$ before calculating the posterior distribution.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Example which gives the posterior as (in the notation of this problem) beta(a+k,b+n-k), and so you can find $\mathbb{P}(\theta>0.3)$